# Transparency between different Kafka Direct Stream functions in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am writing a simple spark-streaming job using Kafka direct stream. Kafka direct stream can be created using two types of methods.

1. Take offset from Kafka Params -

   `createDirectStream[K, V, KD <: Decoder[K], VD <: Decoder[V]](jssc: JavaStreamingContext, keyClass: Class[K], valueClass: Class[V], keyDecoderClass: Class[KD], valueDecoderClass: Class[VD], kafkaParams: Map[String, String], topics: Set[String]): JavaPairInputDStream[K, V]`
2. Supply Offset -

   `createDirectStream[K, V, KD <: Decoder[K], VD <: Decoder[V], R](jssc: JavaStreamingContext, keyClass: Class[K], valueClass: Class[V], keyDecoderClass: Class[KD], valueDecoderClass: Class[VD], recordClass: Class[R], kafkaParams: Map[String, String], fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long], messageHandler: Function[MessageAndMetadata[K, V], R]): JavaInputDStream[R]`

As can be seen from the definitions the return type of both functions is different. I want to create a method on one of the above function based on a map which if empty should revert to the second method otherwise use the first method for creation of streams. However since the both functions have different return types the rest of my code cannot remain transparent to the fact that how was the directStream created. Is there a more elegant way to attain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I was plain stupid. Just posting this in case someone else gets stuck. You can specify the offset through the function:

```
createDirectStream[K, V, KD <: Decoder[K], VD <: Decoder[V], R](jssc: JavaStreamingContext, keyClass: Class[K], valueClass: Class[V], keyDecoderClass: Class[KD], valueDecoderClass: Class[VD], recordClass: Class[R], kafkaParams: Map[String, String], fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long], messageHandler: Function[MessageAndMetadata[K, V], R]): JavaInputDStream[R]
```

The output stream contains the data type `JavaInputDStream[R]`. All that is needed is to supply a function that effectively converts from `MessageAndMetadata[K,V]` to `R`. This can be achieved through the function `messageHandler` in the constructor. All I had to do was add the following line as the messageHandler.

```
(mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mmd.key() -> mmd.message())
```

I needed a `Tuple2`. You can convert it to any datatype you wish.

Comment: Can you please clearly mention what you did to resolve this?